# Internal pipe flow - Pressure Drop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, flow

Let's say I have internal flow at some flow rate in a pipe that is 10 ft long and there are 2 straight sections and 2 bends. I am trying to determine pressure drop due to friction in the pipe. My usual process is this:

1. Determine developed or undeveloped flow.
2. Determine Reynold's Number
3. Determine Friction factor
4. Determine Pressure drop

What I wanted to do was split the pipe into 4 sections and then perform the steps on each section. The add up all the pressure drops.

Another method was to treat it as one pipe that is 10 feet long and perform all the steps on one pipe.

The problem is I get different pressure drops when I perform both methods. The flow is turbulent and undeveloped in the entire pipe is that helps. should the pressure drop be the same for both methods?

Comment: At first glance, I would expect to get the same pressure drop, unless I had compressible flow or diameter changes.  For incompressible flow, all the same diameter, all the same roughness, all the same viscosity, I would expect to get the same pressure drop.  What I would NOT do, for example, is consider 4 ft of straight pipe, first bend, 4 ft of straight, second bend, as four sections, instead of considering one section with 10 ft of pipe and 2 bends.

Comment: @Louis So for undeveloped flow, I have an interpolation table that determines $f$ through Reynold's number and L/D. So I separated the pipe into like you said, a 3 ft straight, 2 ft bend, 3 ft straight and 2 ft bend. I then found the Reynold's number and L/D for each section to determine each section's $f$ and each section's Pressure drop. This did not end up being the same as taking the entire 10ft pipe and finding its L/D, f, and pressure drop. So separating the pipe gave me a different f at each section because each section had a different L/D than the entire pipe.

Comment: First, I misread your question about undeveloped flow.  I thought it was fully developed.  The friction factor that I use for fully developed from does not depend on L/D, but is does depend on the relative roughness, $\epsilon/D$.  I am not familiar with any pressure drop calculation methods for undeveloped region.  Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @Louis Thank you for the help anyway. I have not done any calculations with undeveloped flow either so this is my first time which is why its confusing. If it was fully developed then it would be very easy and I could in fact split the pipe into separate sections (for organization purposes) without having any difficulty